# what do i write to fill the space of the line 4 code such that it prints true if n is a prime since it returns true no matter what

Tags: python

i mathematically find it difficult to compose a code to fill the line 4 in the below code

```
is_prime = True
for i in range(2,n):
    if n%i == 0:
        print("impossible")
print(is_prime)
```

i have been typing print(string) i.e

print("this is not possible")
in the blank and it output

```
true
```

what is the correct code to write. i want to believe it is a mathematics expression thing.i don't know the code to write after if.

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is a prime number, then `n%i == 0` will always be false in your loop. That's why the `print` in the 4th line is never called (you said it yourself, it's impossible). The `true` you are getting is from the `print` on the last line: you never update the value of `is_prime`, so it will always print `True`.

On the other hand, if what you want to know is *if* `n` is a prime number, you can do this:

```
is_prime = True
for i in range(2,n):
    if n%i == 0:
        is_prime = False
        break
print(is_prime)
```

Answer (score 0):

here i wrote it down for you, getting to mathematics what we know is any number is prime number if it can give a integer when it is divided by one or itself so now we can check if the number is divisible by any number in between
for example if your number is equal to 5 then we check if 5 gives an integer and leaves no remainder when divided by 2,3 and 4, you can program this algorithm as follows

```
x=8 #any number to check for

answer= "prime"
for i in range(1,x-1):
    if(x%(i+1) == 0 ):
        answer="non-prime"
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not reassigning `is_prime` to False when your if condition is passed.  After `print("impossible)` you can simply add `is_prime = False` and follow that with a break statement to exit the for loop.

`print(is_prime)` will now return `False`.

You can also modify `range(2, n)` to `range(2, n//2)` (the // operator performs integer divison and leaves no remainder).  This is because for any given number, you will only need to check half of numbers from 1 to n, as eventually you will start to encounter repeated numbers.

```
is_prime = True
for i in range(2, n //2):
    if n % i == 0:
        print("impossible")
        is_prime = False
        break
print(is_prime)
```

Answer (score 0):

from your code, the print statement is on the outer scope from the if condition. You woud try adding an else block. I have have included an example using your code. Hope it helps.

```
is_prime = True
n =10
for i in range(2,n):
    print(i)
    if n%i == 0:
        print("impossible")
    else:
        print(is_prime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `print("impossible")` to any of the following two approaches:

```
is_prime = False
```

**or**

```
not any([n%i==0 for i in range(2,n)])
```